# Box.com super account to get all the box.com users folders and files

Tags: box-api

I have a user cases to get all the box.com users folders and files through one single box.com super service account authentication without each single user's credentials like google drive did. Is it a way to do that through box.com api?

Eric

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can if you have an enterprise account. You can use On-Behalf-Of feature in V2 API and can see other managed users' files and folders by authenticating as enterprise admin. Box will have to enable the On-Behalf-Of feature before you try this in your app.